# Can't decode JSON from Javascript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, post

i'm passing a JSON from javascript to PHP inside an ajax question.
Json is this (printed from PHP, without json_decode):

```
[{"id":"440","step":"1","pass_rules":{"manual":false,"check_percent":true,"quiz":false,"list_element":["id1"]}},{"id":"438","step":"2","pass_rules":{"manual":false,"check_percent":true,"quiz":true,"list_element":["id1"]}}]
```

Is passed though an ajax:

```
    var formData = new FormData(this);   
    formData.append('array', JSON.stringify(fullArray));

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: URL_API + "/call_to_api",
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false, 
            success: function (json) {
            //code 
         }
       })
```

If get array in this way from PHP, i can print the json like the json on top of the post

```
 $array = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['array']);
```

json_decode is not working on the element, and print empty. 
I don't undestand why!

UPDATE: array is passed inside the form in this way:

```
array: [{"id":"441","step":"1","pass_rules":{"manual":false,"check_percent":true,"quiz":false,"list_video":[]}},{"id":"438","step":"3","pass_rules":{"manual":false,"check_percent":true,"quiz":true,"list_video":[]}}]
```

json_last_error() called here:

```
$array= json_decode($_POST['array']); 
json_last_error();
```

json_last_error returns 4 so JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX...but JSON seems good :/

UPDATE2: var_dump output:

```
string(388) "[{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;441&quot;,&quot;step&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;pass_rules&quot;:{&quot;manual&quot;:false,&quot;check_percent&quot;:true,&quot;quiz&quot;:false,&quot;list_video&quot;:[]}},{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;438&quot;,&quot;step&quot;:&quot;3&quot;,&quot;pass_rules&quot;:{&quot;manual&quot;:false,&quot;check_percent&quot;:true,&quot;quiz&quot;:true,&quot;list_video&quot;:[]}}]"
```

Comment: I would guess that `ksql_real_escape_string()` is unnecessary and in fact the cause of the problem.

Comment: that is a function custom, same as mysql_real_escape_string(). Already tried to not using it, get the same empty output

Comment: `json_decode` works just fine on the json

Comment: If the function modifies the JSON string, it will likely do so in a way that makes it no longer be valid JSON.

Comment: [json_last_error — Returns the last error occurred](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php)

Comment: updated with json_last_error ouptut (4)

Comment: We can't duplicate it. What do you get if you `var_dump($_POST['array']);`? Show the full string including the type/count.

Comment: Added on the post!

Comment: There's the problem. Someone/thing has encoded all of the html entities. Use [html_entity_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) first

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).